# Secure LDAP TLS handshake error

Tags: java, ldap

I am trying to change existing LDAP authentication code over the using Secure LDAP.  However, while normal LDAP works, Secure LDAP is failing with an SSLHandshakeException.  A basic code example I have is this:

```
final Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://thehost.net:636");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "id@thehost.net");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
try { final InitialDirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env); }
catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

And the result I get after running the code with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` is:

```
IBMJSSEProvider2 Build-Level: -20120224
Installed Providers = 
    IBMJSSE2
    IBMJCE
    IBMJGSSProvider
    IBMCertPath
    IBMSASL
    IBMXMLCRYPTO
    IBMXMLEnc
    IBMSPNEGO
    SUN
keyStore is: C:\IBM\SDP85\jdk\jre\lib\security\cacerts
keyStore type is: jks
keyStore provider is: 
init keystore
init keymanager of type IbmX509
trustStore is: C:\IBM\SDP85\jdk\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is: jks
trustStore provider is: 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
<...lots...>

SSLContextImpl:  Using X509ExtendedKeyManager com.ibm.jsse2.uc
SSLContextImpl:  Using X509TrustManager com.ibm.jsse2.yc
JsseJCE:  Using SecureRandom  from provider IBMJCE version 1.7
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
IBMJSSE2 will not enable CBC protection
JsseJCE:  Using cipher AES/CBC/NoPadding from provider TBD via init 
JsseJCE:  Using SecureRandom  from provider IBMJCE version 1.7
JsseJCE:  Using KeyAgreement ECDH from provider IBMJCE version 1.7
JsseJCE:  Using signature SHA1withECDSA from provider TBD via init 
JsseJCE:  Using signature NONEwithECDSA from provider TBD via init 
JsseJCE:  Using KeyFactory EC from provider IBMJCE version 1.7
JsseJCE:  Using KeyPairGenerator EC from provider TBD via init 
JsseJce:  EC is available
IBMJSSE2 will allow RFC 5746 renegotiation per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiate set to none or default
IBMJSSE2 will not require renegotiation indicator during initial handshake per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiation.indicator set to OPTIONAL or default taken
IBMJSSE2 will not perform identity checking against the peer cert check during renegotiation per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiation.peer.cert.check set to OFF or default

Is initial handshake: true
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1473523168 bytes = { 226, 146, 195, 134, 254, 178, 154, 160, 71, 118, 157, 13, 255, 234, 173, 207, 224, 49, 60, 249, 136, 124, 112, 41, 169, 88, 54, 229 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp192r1, secp224r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, secp192k1, secp224k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: thehost.net]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 144
<hex code>

Thread-5, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 144
[Raw write]: length = 149
<hex code>

Thread-5, received EOFException: error
Thread-5, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
Thread-5, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
Thread-5, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 28                               .......

Thread-5, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

Is this error being caused by something I'm not setting up correctly in my code?  Or is this a server-side issue?  I've done some searching, and this seems like it would be correct, but I'm not very familiar with either LDAP or SSL/TLS.